# Prove that we can convert any given turing machine to a turing machine with only 3 states?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, automata

So in a book that I'm reading it says that we can convert any given Turing machine to a *standard* turing machine with only 6 states

furthermore we can convert any given to a turing machine with only 3 states given we have no limitation on which version of turing machine we use(multi tape, non deterministic, etc so its not a standard turing machine anymore) and obviously both the original turing machine and the converted one have the same functionality(accept the same language)

i asked this here before but no one was able to give   a proof of this, and i do not understand it either

so what's this statement based on? i tried searching the web but there was literally 0 article about this.

I think this is done the same way we can reduce any PDA to a PDA with only 3 states, but i dont know the prove of that one either, i just know its true

Comment: *I asked this here before.* You should include a link to your earlier question.

Comment: Here is the earlier question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/89765/can-we-convert-any-given-turing-machine-to-a-turing-machine-with-only-2-states.

Comment: See also https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43517/what-is-the-limit-for-turing-machines-with-2-states-and-3-symbols-that-halt.

Comment: What's the difference from the old question?

Comment: @xskxzr in the old one i said 2 states but that was not right, the correct minimum is 3, and i have not found the prove yet ( but i think reducing the number of states is done the same way that we can reduce any given PDA to a PDA with only 2 states, but i dont know the prove of that one either) all of these are side notes in the book without any prove

Comment: It would likely be helpful if you cited the book.

Comment: @DerekElkins Its a translation of peter linz - automata  in the turing machine chapter, not sure if these side notes are in the original book or not